# Show that $I = \frac{\rho + \sigma_x\rho\sigma_x +\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y + \sigma_z\rho\sigma_z}{2}$ for all states $\rho$

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix, textbook-and-exercises

I am trying to show that for any qubit state p, the following holds:

$$I = \frac{\rho  + \sigma_x\rho\sigma_x +\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y  + \sigma_z\rho\sigma_z}{2}$$

I have tried different manipulations, but got stuck... Will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Since there are many answers now and it is a "textbook" question, let me ask, what did you try? Because all you need is to know the properties of the Pauli matrices and how to represent a qubit state in the Bloch representation.

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary one qubit density matrix we have:

$$\rho = \frac{I}{2} + \frac{r_x \sigma_x + r_y \sigma_y + r_z \sigma_z}{2}$$

where $|r| \le 1$. Here we should take into account that $\sigma_i  \sigma_j  \sigma_i = -\sigma_j$ where $i \ne j$ and $i, j \in \{x, y, z\}$, and, also $\sigma_i\sigma_i=I$. With this we will obtain the equality presented in the question. Let's see, for example what will be equal the $\sigma_x \rho \sigma_x$ term:

$$\sigma_x \rho \sigma_x = \frac{I}{2} + \frac{r_x \sigma_x - r_y \sigma_y - r_z \sigma_z}{2}$$

Similarly, we will obtain:

$$\frac{\rho  + \sigma_x\rho\sigma_x +\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y  + \sigma_z\rho\sigma_z}{2} = \\
=I + \frac{2r_x \sigma_x + 2r_y \sigma_y + 2r_z \sigma_z -2r_x \sigma_x - 2r_y \sigma_y - 2r_z \sigma_z}{2} = I $$

Answer (score 2):

This method is largely similar to Davit's (this covers a slightly more general case where $\rho$ is any arbitrary matrix with trace 1, and you easily see how to adjust it without the trace 1 condition). Any $2\times 2$ matrix can be decomposed as $aI+\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ if we allow $a$ and $\vec{n}$ to take on arbitrary complex values. Moreover, two $2\times 2$ matrices are equal if an only if their values of $a$ and $\vec{n}$ are equal. So, let
$$
\tau=\frac{\rho  + \sigma_x\rho\sigma_x +\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y  + \sigma_z\rho\sigma_z}{2}.
$$
We want to show that $a=1$ and $\vec{n}=0$. Now,
$$
a=\text{Tr}(\tau)/2,\qquad n_i=\text{Tr}(\sigma_i\tau)/2.
$$
Remember that trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, so
$$
a=\frac{1}{4}\text{Tr}(\rho  + \sigma_x\rho\sigma_x +\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y  + \sigma_z\rho\sigma_z)=\frac{1}{4}\text{Tr}(\rho  + \rho\sigma_x^2 +\rho\sigma_y^2  + \rho\sigma_z^2)=\text{Tr}(\rho)=1.
$$
Similarly,
$$
n_x=\frac12\text{Tr}(\sigma_x\rho  + \rho\sigma_x +\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y  + \sigma_x\sigma_z\rho\sigma_z)=\frac12\text{Tr}(2\sigma_x\rho +\rho\sigma_y\sigma_x\sigma_y  + \rho\sigma_z\sigma_x\sigma_z).
$$
Now use the anti-commutation properties of the Pauli matrices to get
$$
n_x=\frac12\text{Tr}(2\rho\sigma_x -\rho\sigma_x  - \rho\sigma_x)=0.
$$
The other two components are just the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special instance of a general linear algebra result.

Note that the identity matrix $\newcommand{\vec}{\operatorname{vec}}I$ can be decomposed as $I=\sum_k v_k\otimes v_k^*$ for any orthonormal basis $\{v_k\}_k$, and vice versa any such decomposition identifies the identity matrix.

Now notice that the Pauli matrices are an orthonormal basis in an enlarged Hilbert space, meaning that
$$\operatorname{Tr}[(\sigma_i/\sqrt2)(\sigma_j/\sqrt2)]=\delta_{ij}.$$
More explicitly, this is saying that we can think of the *matrices* $\sigma_i$ as orthonormal *vectors* in some space, $i.e.$ we have
$\langle \vec(\sigma_i/\sqrt2),\vec(\sigma_j/\sqrt2)\rangle=\delta_{ij}$, where $\vec(B)$ is the vectorisation of the operator $B$.

---

If $A_a\in\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal X,\mathcal Y)$ are a set of such orthonormal operators, we have
$$\mathrm{tr}(A_a^\dagger A_b)=\delta_{ab} \Longleftrightarrow \langle\mathrm{vec}(A_a),\mathrm{vec}(A_b)\rangle=\delta_{ab},$$
where $\vec(A_a)\in\mathcal Y\otimes\mathcal X$ is the vectorisation of $A_a$.
If the set is a basis, then we also have
$$\sum_a (A_a)_{12} (A_a^*)_{34} = \delta_{13}\delta_{24}
\Longleftrightarrow
\sum_a\vec(A_a)\vec(A_a)^\dagger = I_{\mathcal Y\otimes\mathcal X}
$$
Now, the statement we are interested in is of the form
$\sum_a A_a \rho A_a^\dagger = I$. This amounts to
$$ \sum_{a34} (A_a)_{13} (A_a^*)_{24} \rho_{34} = \delta_{12}
\Longleftrightarrow
\sum_a (A_a\otimes A_a^*)\vec(\rho) = \lvert m\rangle,
$$
where $\lvert m\rangle\equiv\sum_k \lvert k,k\rangle$.
The question is thus, what type of operator is $\sum_a A_a\otimes A_a^*$?
Componentwise, the relation with $\sum_a \vec(A_a)\vec(A_a)^\dagger$ is clear:
$$(A_a\otimes A_a^*)_{ij,nm} = (A_a)_{in} (A_a^*)_{jm}
= (\vec(A_a)\vec(A_a)^\dagger)_{in,jm} = \delta_{ij}\delta_{nm},$$
that is, $A_a\otimes A_a^*$ is the *Choi* of $\vec(A_a)\vec(A_a)^\dagger$. Summing over $a$ this is the identity, which means that $\sum_a A_a\otimes A_a^*$ is the Choi of the identity, which is the projector over the maximally entangled state:
$$\sum_a A_a\otimes A_a^*=\lvert m\rangle\!\langle m\rvert.$$
We conclude that
$$\sum_A A_a \rho A_a^\dagger 
= \operatorname{unvec}\left(\sum_a (A_a\otimes A_a^*) \vec(\rho)\right)
= \operatorname{unvec}(\lvert m\rangle ) = I_{\mathcal X}.$$

Comment: It's not quite clear how it's equivalent to the question statement.

Comment: @DanyloY I added some more detail. Makes more sense now?

Comment: The idea is clear, though the details look a little bit messed up. The common vectorization formula is $\operatorname{vec}(ABC) = (C^T \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)$. Also note that $\sigma_y^T = -\sigma_y$.

Comment: @DanyloY indeed, going carefully over the steps there were a few more formal steps required. I guess one can state the result concisely as (1) thinking of the statement as a map acting on a state, the $\sigma_i$ are understood as Kraus ops (2) switching in the natural representation it becomes a question of what is $\sum_a A_a\otimes A_a^*$ (3) the Choi of $A\otimes A^*$ is $\mathrm{vec}(A)\mathrm{vec}(A)^\dagger$ (4) the latter is the identity if the vectorised ops are a basis. I have to say though, I think it's much easier to think componentwise here

Comment: regarding the "vectorisation formula", I gues it depends on the convention? I'm simply using $\mathrm{vec}(A)_{12}=A_{12}$, thus $\mathrm{vec}(ABC)_{12}=(ABC)_{12}=A_{13}B_{34}C_{42}=[(A\otimes C^T)B]_{12}$. I'm not sure what is the point of your pointing out $\sigma_y^T=-\sigma_y$.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I feel like giving, imo, the simplest answer following the question specified in N&C.

Firstly as specified in the question define:

$ \mathcal{E}(A) = \frac{A + XAX + YAY + ZAZ}{4}$ .

It it is easy to see that

$ \mathcal{E}(I) = \frac{I + XIX + YIY + ZIZ}{4} = \frac{I + XX + YY + ZZ}{4} = I$

For the other three quantities $\mathcal{E}(X),\mathcal{E}(Y),\mathcal{E}(Z)$ we can make use of the elementary identities:

$\sigma_i\sigma_i\sigma_i = \sigma_i$

$\sigma_i\sigma_j\sigma_i = -\sigma_j$

Plugging in these identities we can see $\mathcal{E}(X),\mathcal{E}(Y),\mathcal{E}(Z) = 0$. More generally, (after grouping the terms), we can see that:

$ \mathcal{E}(\sigma_i) = \frac{2\sigma_i - 2\sigma_i}{4} = 0$

Finally we know from e.q 2.175 that

$\rho = \frac{I + \vec{r} \cdot\vec{\sigma}}{2} = \frac{I + r_x\sigma_x + r_y\sigma_y + r_z\sigma_z}{2}$,

and plugging this into

$\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \frac{\mathcal{E}(I) + \mathcal{E}(r_x\sigma_x) + \mathcal{E}(r_y\sigma_y) + \mathcal{E}(r_z\sigma_z)}{2}$,

using the results from above we see all the $\mathcal{E}(r_i\sigma_i)=0$, leaving us just with

$\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \frac{\mathcal{E}\left({I}\right)}{2} = \frac{I}{2}$,

finally to complete the proof

$2\mathcal{E}(\rho) = I$

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're only working with a single qubit state it is possible to also show this by direct calculation on a parametrised state. That is, we can write any single qubit $\rho$ as
$$
\rho = \begin{pmatrix}
a & \beta \\
\overline{\beta} & 1-a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a\in[0,1]$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(1-2a)^2  + 4 |\beta|^2 \leq 1$. Then we can directly compute the action of the Pauli conjugation
$$
\sigma_x \rho \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 
1-a & \overline{\beta} \\
\beta & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\sigma_y \rho \sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix} 
1-a & -\overline{\beta} \\
-\beta & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\sigma_z \rho \sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} 
a & -\beta \\
-\overline{\beta} & 1-a
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Summing these up with $\rho$ and dividing through by $2$ we get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter VII. E. in [Daniel Lidar's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00967.pdf) notes. Use $\rho = \frac{1}{2}(I + \vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})$ and products of Pauli matrices:

Check for each pair that:
$\sigma_i \sigma_j = \delta_{ij} I + i \epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$

Use it to show:
$
\sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k = \delta_{ij} \sigma_k - \delta_{ik} \sigma_j + \delta_{jk} \sigma_i 
+ i \epsilon_{ijk} I
$

One more step
$
\sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_i = 
2\delta_{ij} \sigma_i - \sigma_j = 
\begin{cases}
+\sigma_j &, i = j\\
-\sigma_j &, i \neq j
\end{cases}
$

with this go to eq. 189 from [Daniel Lidar](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00967.pdf):
$$
\sigma_x(I + \vec{v}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sigma_x = 
I + v_x \sigma_x - v_y \sigma_y - v_z \sigma_z
$$
$$
\sigma_y(I + \vec{v}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sigma_y = 
I - v_x \sigma_x + v_y \sigma_y - v_z \sigma_z
$$
$$
\sigma_z(I + \vec{v}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sigma_z = 
I - v_x \sigma_x - v_y \sigma_y + v_z \sigma_z
$$

add it together with
$$
I(I + \vec{v}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) I = 
I + v_x \sigma_x + v_y \sigma_y + v_z \sigma_z
$$

to get
$$
2(\rho 
+ \sigma_x \rho \sigma_x 
+ \sigma_y \rho \sigma_y 
+ \sigma_z \rho \sigma_z) 
= 
4I
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\rho$ is a pure state, these are the explicit calculations. You can easily generalize to mixed states.

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|{#1}\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle{#1}|}$
Let $\ket{\psi} = \alpha\ket{0}+ \beta\ket{1}$, where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}^2$ and $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$.

Thus $\rho = \ket{\psi}\bra{\psi} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha\alpha^* & \alpha\beta^* \\ \beta\alpha^* & \beta\beta^*\end{pmatrix}$.

Now $\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, so $ \sigma_x \rho \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} \beta\beta^* & \beta\alpha^* \\ \alpha\beta^* & \alpha\alpha^*\end{pmatrix}$.

Similarly, you can compute $\sigma_y\rho\sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix} \beta\beta^* & -\beta\alpha^* \\ -\alpha\beta^* & \alpha\alpha^*\end{pmatrix}$ and $\sigma_z\rho\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha\alpha* & -\alpha\beta* \\ -\beta\alpha* & \beta\beta*\end{pmatrix}$.

Finally, summing up:

$\frac{1}{2} (\rho + \sigma_x \rho \sigma_x + \sigma_y \rho \sigma_y + \sigma_z \rho \sigma_z) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2(\alpha\alpha^* + \beta\beta^*) & 0 \\ 0 & 2(\alpha\alpha^* + \beta\beta^*) \end{pmatrix}  = I$.